# How to create a nuxt3 starter template

Tags: nuxtjs3

I want to create a starter template with nuxt3 that includes `tailwindcss` , `nuxt icons`

A pages and layouts folder with and `index.vue` and `default.vue` pages respectively

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: I believe I not understand what is your question. But one solution it's create a repo no github and uses this repo with uses as template